# What is the expected value of half a standard normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

You have a normal distribution with mean of 0 and variance of 1.  Keeping the same probabilities and focusing only on half of the distribution (other half has it's original probabilities but x values of 0) what is the expected value of this?

Im trying to teach myself expected outcomes with weird constraints.  I got 0.3989, hopefully this is right.

Comment: this may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution

Comment: Welcome to CV, vt_og. Which half?

Comment: well the positive half.  I would assume the negative half woudl just be -0.3989

Comment: There are two parts to answering this question: (1) finding a formula for the distribution and (2) computing the integral.  With which part do you need help?

Answer (score 3):

If we let $Z \sim \text{N}(0,1)$ denote a standard normal random variable, the random variable $|Z|$ follows a standard [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) (the *positive* half of the standard normal distribution)  and has $\mathbb{E}(|Z|) = \sqrt{2/\pi}$.  This means that:

$$\mathbb{E}(\max(Z,0)) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbb{E}(|Z|) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \approx 0.3989423,$$

$$\mathbb{E}(\min(-Z,0)) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \mathbb{E}(-|Z|) = -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \approx -0.3989423.$$